# Plotting y'[x] vs y[x]

Tags: plotting

I solved a differential equation numerically and I want to Plot y'[x] vs. y[x], but I don't know how.
what is the command?

Comment: ParametricPlot?

Comment: See the third example in the docs for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html).

Answer (score 6):

It would be easiest to use a ParametricPlot, for instance:

```
{y[x], y'[x]}/.NDSolve[{y''[x] == Sin[y'[x]] - y[x], y[0] == 2, y'[0] == -1}, 
  y, {x, 0, 10}]
ParametricPlot[%, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Here you have solved the equation numerically, and you take out the solutions {y[x],y'[x]} using the /. command. Then using a ParametricPlot this gives the following:

[image: parametric solution]